# Effect on Sharepoint installation of Active Directory Upgrade

Tags: windows-server-2008, sharepoint-2007

We have a customer that runs sharepoint (MOSS) 2007 on a windows 2003 domain. (Sharepoint is not on the domain controller)

The customer would like to upgrade the domain controllers to Windows 2008 R2.

Initially the Sharepoint solution will remain on a Windows 2003 server.

Are there any gotchas or things that we need to watchout for in relation to the upgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We run Moss 2007 and experienced no issues when upgrading our DC's to W2K8.

Comment: Which domain functional level are you running on?

Comment: We're currently at W2K8 functional level. When we upgraded our DC's we were at W2K3 functional level and remained there for a period of time after the upgrade before raising it. We did also upgrade our W2K3 Moss 2007 server to W2K8. I don't remember if there were any caveats when we upgraded the MOSS server so do your research before moving forward with upgrading the MOSS server.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I don't think so. You didn't specify which version of SharePoint you're running.

You might want to check up on the [SharePoint support site](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx/ph/11373).

Answer (score 1):

Changing the domain controllers should be fine, as long as you keep the domain. If you need to recreate the domain (user id's etc) that'd be 'bad'.

Also, changing the AD schema would potentially be bad also.

Changing the domain functional level should be ok though, if you need to (as long as you are above 'Windows 2003', which you will be).

Comment: Upgrading the DC's to W2K8 will change the shema. AFAIK, this doesn't have any effect on Moss 2007.

Comment: The domain functional level does not change automatically as a result of upgrading the DC's to W2K8.